# Importing certificate in keytool doesnt solve java certificate issue

Tags: java, security, spring-security

I am trying to hit one of the github APi and get repose through it. But i get certification issue when i am trying to hit that APi in java code. I am getting the response in postman

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to restart your server after importing keytool and try once again the same.